# Rendering QWebView with flash

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, xvfb

I'm trying to get a screen capture of a web page with a flash object in it. The page I'm trying to render is http://www.swellinfo.com/surf-forecast/san-jose-guatemala.html, specifically the swell flash object. I'm loading the page in a QWebView in Xvfb using the Ghost.py framework. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Flash rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many screen-captures have problems with hardware accelerated windows, so try to [disable hardware accelleration](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891337) when capturing.

Comment: Would hardware acceleration be in issue with no GPU?

Comment: You're right, with Xvfb this probably doesn't matter. Which settings do you use to start Xvfb? It starts with a screen mode of `1280x1024x8` per default... If I start it with something like `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x24` I can take a shot of a QWebView with flash without problems.

Comment: I believe the 8-bit depth was causing the problem. Switched to x24 and everything renders fine. Thanks!